# Using FFMpeg with Twilight Render

Tags: mp4

I have installed FFmpeg for creating mp4 files from a sequence of images generated with the animation editor in Twilight Render. I then try to generate an mp4 file, but I do not get a valid mp4 file. I have not been able to figure out what I am doing/have done wrong.

Comment: What are the commands you used? Any error messages? How do you check if a file is valid? What is your OS? Please [edit] the question and be specific.